# ModuleNotFoundError: by importing function from my own module

Tags: python, python-import

i have the following project structure:

```
-dags
----script1.py
----script2.py
----projects

--------project1
------------modules
----------------__init__.py
----------------module1.py
----------------module2.py
----------------module3.py

--------project2
------------modules
----------------__init__.py
----------------module1.py
----------------module2.py
----------------module3.py
```

my `module1.py`:

```
import sklearn
import pandas as pd

def some_func(X,y):
    res = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression(X,y)
    print('Execute function)
    return res
```

When I import my function into `script1.py` file and try to run to run the function I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'`

Import is done in the following way:

```
from projects.project1.modules.module1 import some_func
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Is scikit-learn installed on your machine (and environment)?

Comment: @OnY yes. When y put all imports inside my function, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No module name sklearn refers that python can't find any module named sklearn installed.
Try installing it, if already installed then try updating.

To install

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

To update

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

or if you are using a virtual environment, then use

```
python -m venv sklearn-venv

sklearn-venv\Scripts\activate

pip install -U scikit-learn
```